# Arcade game from 80s or 90s about a doctor and spray

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

I recall (vaguely) being a doctor/scientist who had a spray can to kill bugs/enemies. Not remembering the name is driving me crazy! Help! :-)

It is not Dr. Mario.

Comment: Some additional details would be helpful.  Was it top-down, side, or isometric? What did the bugs / enemies look like?  How was the spray can controlled (mouse, direction keys, ...?) Multiple levels? Goals?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see that 'some arcade game someone played' has anything to do with this site's focus on retrocomputing.

Comment: What are old arcade games if not retrocomputers? They're computers, and they're old and out of date. That's like half the hobby. It's fine if you just want to restore PDP-5's and IBM 1401's but old arcade games certainly belong here.

Comment: I feel that it is on-topic, but desperately needs more info.

Comment: @Greenonline It's a borderline issue. Use of arcade games is neither  about computing nor computers but gaming. Even more if it's bar of all details - and that's what I see another-dave pointing out.

Comment: Those who think that we absolutely should have questions about old arcade games might want to elaborate for their reasons in an answer here: https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/what-does-the-site-gain-from-identify-this-game-i-vaguely-remember-questions

Comment: Shall we have questions about every non-user-programmable appliance (of sufficient vintage) that has been constructed using a computer?  What makes an arcade game different from a washing machine in terms of suitability for retrocomputing?

Comment: ISTR there's also a sister site called arquade or something similar. It may be worth asking over there. Also the fact this site has a tag for identify-this-game, reasonably old and with 129 questions currently, seems to indicate it's a valid question?

Comment: @paxdiablo Unfortunately, this question is off-topic at Arqade. [Arqade does not allow the identification of games from memory without media from the game itself.](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10197/4797)

Comment: @NelsonAraujo If you recall any sci-fi (e.g., futuristic/fictional technology), fantasy, supernatural, or other similar elements in the game, you might want to ask your question on our sister site, [scifi.se] SE. They accept identification requests for games with speculative fiction elements. Consider posting there, but make sure to check their [identification guidelines](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957) first.

Comment: Thanks, everybody, for the feedback. I looked at various other forums, and this looked like a good home for the question.

Comment: Some additional details would be helpful. Was it top-down, side, or isometric? What did the bugs / enemies look like? How was the spray can controlled (mouse, direction keys, ...?) Multiple levels? Goals?

@fadden

It was side scrolling. It was in an arcade machine (not for computer or home console)

Comment: @NelsonAraujo: you could also try https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/

Comment: For anyone curious: the game is "Tricky Doc"; see https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/174a5z7/arcade80s_or_90s_about_a_doctor_and_bug_spray/

Answer (score 2):

Donkey Kong 3 had a little guy with a can of bug spray, go have a look for it and see if it's the right one.